# Using negative lookahead in RegExp to correctly match image URLs wrapped in [img] tags?

Tags: regex, imageurl, regex-look-ahead

Negative lookahead to match itself in RegExp

I want to use a RegExp to match an image url that will have two cases:

The first case it is a normal image URL, ending with `.png` and may contain some query string, at which point the RegExp will match it in its entirety.

`https://test.com/cat.png?pkey=abcd`

In the second case, the URL is wrapped in an **`[img][/img]`** tag,  the RegExp will be expected **not** to any string.

`[img]https://test.com/cat.png?pkey=abcd[/img]`

Now I have written this regular expression, it works great on the first case

`(https:\/\/.*?\.png(?:\?[\w&=_-]*)?)(?!\[)`

however it does not work with the second case, it will still be matched up to the penultimate character of the URL. How can I modify my RegExp to achieve my goal?

Here's RegExp link: https://regexr.com/7eohf

Comment: In such cases, a safer approach is to match and capture what you need, and just match what you do not need. `\[img][^]*?\[\/img]|(https:\/\/[^?\]\[\s]*?\.png(?:\?[\w&=_\-]*)?)`, something like that.

Comment: If you have found an answer that works for you, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.

Comment: If [possessive quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) are supported: [`https:\/\/\S*?\.png(?:\?[-\w&=]*)?+(?!\[)`](https://regex101.com/r/Cf7LPt/1) but from your demo it looks like you are using JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to ancitipate the lookahead immediately after `.png`:

```
(https:\/\/.*?\.png(?!\S*\[)(?:\?[\w&=_-]*)?)
```

Where `\S` matches any character that is not a space (you can replace it as you wish).

See a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/ZK5wVV/1).

Alternatively, you can impose that the last character matched is not followed by `[?\w&=_-]`:

```
(https:\/\/.*?\.png(?:\?[\w&=_-]*)?)(?![?\w&=_-]|\[)
```

Comment: if I want to support hashtag(#) in url, how can I achieve it?

Comment: You should be more precise on what do you want to achieve (probably you should open a new question).